# React native in app icon badge notifications according to firebase / firestore documents

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using

- React Native
- OneSignal for push notifications
- React Navigation
- React Native Elements (Badge component)
- React Native Vector Icons
- Firebase, Firestore as backend

So, inside my app I have two buttons in my topRight Stack Screen

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="CreateEvent"
    component={CreateEvent}
    options={{
        headerRight: () => (
             <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", marginRight: 10 }}>
                   <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => { navigation.navigate("InvitationsNav") }}>
                            <Badge
                                status="error"
                                containerStyle={{ position: 'absolute', top: -4, right: -4 }}
                                value="10"/> // <--- hardcoded value

                                <IconMaterialIcons
                                    name="event"
                                    color={Constants.colors.primaryColor}
                                    backgroundColor="transparent"
                                    size={30}
                                    style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}/>
                   </TouchableOpacity>

                   <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => { navigation.navigate("nl_Notifications") }}>
                            <Badge
                                status="error"
                                containerStyle={{ position: 'absolute', top: -4, right: -4 }}
                                value="2"/> // <--- hardcoded value
                            <IconIonicons
                                name="notifications-outline"
                                color={Constants.colors.primaryColor}
                                backgroundColor="rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.0)"
                                size={30}
                                style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
               </View>)
```

[image: example]

On last image the values are hardcoded.

I want to set those two values dynamically according to not seen firestore documents. I mean if user has not seen those last notifications or events, set that amount of documents not seen on the corresponding badge.

If there are 3 new notifications for that specific user, I want to set a 3 programmatically on the badge.

Or if there are 6 not seen events for that user, I want to set that value on the badge.

Any idea how can I solve this issue?

I guess a solution is to add a flag on the firestore document something like:

```
seen: false
```

and when user press over the notificiation or event change that flag to true, but with this solution I have to pre-load firestore documents with seen == false and I'm not sure that is an economic solution.

Is there any way to set this two values just with the OneSignal Push notification? or maybe another solution ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

What you mentioned here:

> but with this solution I have to pre-load firestore documents with seen == false and I'm not sure that is an economic solution.

This statement is not true, documents in firestore are not required to have an equal structure amongs themselves so you can apply that logic only to new documents (or you could add that to older documents for data consistency only, since the documents will never be "unseen", which I don't think it's a requirement in this case).

I am not familiar with the use of OneSignal for push notifications so I can't say if there is a better solution using that, but as far as Firestore solutions go and since you are still going to need to interact with Firestore somehow to check if the documents are still unseen, the flag option is a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor It helped a lot